# DateTime.UtcNow gives different value in different server

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc

I have a dll that logs datetime in UTC using this code i.e. `DateTime.UtcNow() I am running a console application which uses this dll in two different servers. One server is in 'Easter Timezone' and the other is in 'Pacific Timezone'. Now when i launch the console application, i keep getting two different times.

e.g. 
In Easter  Timezone: 11/18/2014 10:14:40 PM
In Pacific Timezone: 11/18/2014 10:13:26 PM
Difference: 1:14

I launched the console application in the server that was running in EST first. And the time difference between launching two console applications in two servers was just couple seconds. Does anyone know why there is so much difference in timezone (UTC) while running the same code in two different servers?

Thanks.
Sanjeev

Comment: 1 minute 14 seconds?  Sounds like one of your servers isn't getting a properly synced time.  `UtcNow()` uses the local clock and timezone settings, so make sure the local clock is set correctly

Comment: Sounds like you want to sync both servers to the Naval Observatory time clock, and then run your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system clock on both servers could be slightly different.

From the spec (emphasis added):

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time ***on this***
>   ***computer***, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: is there anyway to get utctime computer independent?

Comment: @sanjeev40084: You can ask a single server somewhere, and hope that it doesn't lie and that the network is fast.  This is a hard problem; read about distributed systems development.

Comment: Windows should be able to sync with a time server.  What version of windows are you running?

Comment: depending on the server security policy, it could be that the time sync functionality is blocked or disabled - in which case you might need to sync the servers yourself.

Comment: It's running on Windows 2003 server.  I think running the UTC code in third server and getting the timezone calling from that server on other two servers might be the better options.

Comment: @sanjeev40084 could latency affect that? The time taken for the request to be received and the response received by the application? What is the tolerance for latency?

Comment: @sanjeev40084 This could be useful to you: http://serverfault.com/questions/13253/how-to-synchronize-the-clock-of-a-windows-server-2003-domain-server

Comment: You guys were right. The server that was running in EST was 1 min couple seconds ahead than actual EST. I fixed the time and that took care of it :) Thanks to you all.

Comment: @sanjeev40084 if it was the cause, please mark as answer.